# Securing a service on Google App Engine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, google-app-engine-python

I have two services `default` and `taskworker` that get deployed to app engine's standard environment.

I communicate from default to taskworker via cloud tasks on a few exposed HTTP handlers. E.g: background/check_emails.

I also have a cron job running every minute for background/check_emails.

My deployments of default and taskworker are straightforward e.g:

```
runtime: python37
service: taskworker

handlers:
- url: /background/.*
  script: auto
```

```
runtime: python37
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon.ico
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

Given that I want to continue getting external traffic to "default" and restrict traffic of "taskworker" from everyone except 1) cron job 2) cloud task http requests:

What are my options?

p.s: I'm not very firewall savvy, and the app engine rules for the project seem to affect the whole project, I do not know how to do a service-based firewall.

Comment: Although not strictly made for this purpose, it may be worth checking out [Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/). It may be a little bit of an overkill, but should do the job, although it incurs further charges.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a few headers in your handler to ensure the request is indeed from the Task clouds.

https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#reading_request_headers

X-AppEngine-QueueName is one of them but you can see the doc for more.

The document specifically says "If your request handler finds any of the headers listed above, it can trust that the request is a Cloud Tasks request."

Comment: I think the docs are misleading as I just tested this and I could manually add this header to the request and it was passed through to my handler. (EDIT: False alarm, it was allowing me to set the header because I was authenticated as an admin using IAP)

Answer (score 0):

As of now a "service.based" firewall is not supported for App Engine Standard, the [App Engine firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls) act upon all the services that comprise your application and it doesn't support granularity for each service.

But there is a Feature Request, please go to the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/77891432) in order to check the status of it, notice that there is no ETA or a guarantee that this will be implemented.

As suggested on the Feature Request link shared, the current workaround would consist of migrating your application to App Engine Flexible environment and configure the respective firewall rules on a VPC networks of the Compute Engine instances where your app will reside.